# Getting data from a dynamic sequence of SQL Server tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have an arbitrary sequence of tables "TiSe1" - "TiSeNN" with the same columns in a SQL Server database. This is an archive of measurements by date. How can I combine them in one SQL query to build a report on all tables at once?

Or I need to create a view that dynamically merges all existing "TiSe" tables.

[Tables SCR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/par5b.png)

Comment: I would suggest that you either combine all the data into a singe table or at least create a view.  It is really better to put the data into a single table with a snapshot date.

Comment: Hi! This is an existing SCADA archive from which I am making a report in Jasper Reports. Since I have not worked with Java, I am trying to combine on the SQL side, although you can probably do this in Jasper Reports.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of dynamic SQL can get you there easily:

```
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(4000) = STUFF((
    SELECT ' UNION ALL'+ CHAR(10) +'SELECT * FROM '+ QUOTENAME(PartName) 
    FROM [dbo].[Tables]
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 11, '')

-- When dealing with dynamic SQL, print is your best friend...
PRINT @Sql

-- Once you've visually verified the SQL looks valid, uncomment and execute.
--EXEC(@Sql)
```